# Why are different python modules installed in different locations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I just found something strange and don't know how to fix it.  I found a kludge of a workaround though but would rather not do this if I can help it.

I am working on a MBP 10.9.5.  I upgraded pip to 9.0.1 from 8.0.1.  Then I installed three modules (four if you count the required module)

- image
- pillow
- py2app (required macholib, which it installed automatically)

After the modules are installed, I run pip show on them to see what the locations are.

For some reason, image, pillow and macholib are all installed at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

whereas py2app is installed at

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Do we know why python is splitting up where the modules are installed?  The workaround is to go into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and copy the directories of these modules to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.  However, I'd like to avoid doing this if possible and tell pip to install everything in one location rather than wherever it feels like.

There are no config files found for pip (I can list the dirs I looked at if needed) and if there are secret hidden config files, that doesn't explain why pip is installing module files to multiple locations.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to stop it from happening?

Thanks

Comment: Why is it a problem to have the modules installed in different site-packages directories ?

Comment: @Gribouillis, thanks for your interest in my question.  When I try to import the module, python gives an error and says there's no module of that name.  When I do a pip freeze, it shows the module as installed.  After playing around, I found the workaround made python not complain about no module installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is not in your `sys.path` when you start python, you could find the file named `sitecustomize.py` in the python library directory and add (as super user) the following lines

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

in this file. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, the only locations for this sitecustomize.cy file is either in PyCharm and in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  Ironically, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py already has your lines included in it.  I think I might be hopeless.  Where is the sitecustomize.py file usually found for a standard python install?

Comment: Probably in `/Library/Python/2.7` (but I don't know standard python install on a Mac)

Comment: I guess I'm hopeless.  The cmd 'find / -name "sitecustomize.py"' didn't find it and it's also not in /Library/Python/2.7 either.  =(

Comment: Don't you have the locate command ? Try `updatedb`, then `locate sitecustomize`. Or perhaps in python shell `>>> import sitecustomize; print sitecustomize`

Comment: I might need to go another route.  `import sitecustomize` didn't work.  Python says `ImportError: No module named sitecustomize`.

Comment: Then you can try to create your own `Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py` with the 2 lines above.

Comment: Thx.  That worked.  Thanks for making me NOT hopeless  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130563/discussion-between-classified-and-gribouillis).